# How to pass label id to .js file and change label color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have used following code where i used external .js file as well as inline script function.Inline is working fine and label is changed to green color but when i put same function in .js file then it shows me wrong output

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">


<title></title>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JScript1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<%--<script>
    function onLeave1(_input, _labelInput) {

        var char = /^[A-z]+$/;
        var labelValue = _labelInput;

        var check = _input.value;

        if (_input.value.match(char)) {



            $('.' + _labelInput).css("color", "green");
            //  var someVariable = document.getElementById("Label8").innerHTML;
            // alert(someVariable);


        }
        else {
            $('#Label8').css("color", "red");
        }
    }
</script>--%>
  <style type="text/css">
     .style1
     {
        height: 26px;
      }
     .style2
    {
        height: 26px;
        width: 131px;
    }
    .style3
    {
        width: 131px;
    }
   </style>


  </head>
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>


 <table>

    <tr>

        <td class="style1">

            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl1" Text="First Name:-"></asp:Label>

        </td>

        <td class="style2">

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtID2" runat="server" onblur="onLeave1(this,'Label8')"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Label class="Label8" runat="server"  Text="|" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        </td>



    </tr>



</table>
  </div>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

```
$('#Label8').css("color", "red");
```

to:

```
$('.Label8').css("color", "red");
```

since you've assigned `class="Label8"` to your label